# is it possible to override a foreign key relation with a custom method/property

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-orm

## Context

I'm working on refactoring a Django 2.X app, particularly the core model, `CoreModel`. There's a single database (Postgres) containing all related tables.

Instances of `CoreModel` will no longer live in Postgres after this refactor, they will live somewhere else but outside the scope of the Django project, let's say some AWS No-SQL database service.

There also several satellites models `SateliteModel` to `CoreModel` which will continue to live on Postgres, but `CoreModel`is currently modelled as a foreign key field.

```
class CordeModel(models.Model):
    pass

class SatelliteModel(models.Model):
    core = models.ForeignKey(CoreModel)

    def some_instance_method(self):
       return self.core.calculate_stuff() # <- override self.core!
```

## Problem

The code is filled with mentions to the `CoreModel` relation, and I haven't been able to successfully solved this issue.

My first naive approach was to implement a `@property` getter method, that way I had enough flexibility to do something like:

```
@property
def core(self):
    try:
       # ORM
       return self.core
    except CoreNotFound:
       # External datastore
       return aws_client.fetch_core()
```

With this snippet I have a circular dependency on the `core` name, so the idea is out.

- I could rename the foreign key: but I would much rather not touch the database schema. After all I'm already refactoring the central part of the app, and that's an very error-prone process. I'd do this if there's no other choice.
- I could rename the `@property` field, to something like `current_core`: This way I avoid the infinite recursion part, but this in turn would imply a very big task of searching the whole code base for mentions of the relation, and this being the central model, it would take a lot of time.

After some hours of research I'm beginning to doubt if the concept of overriding a getter for a foreign key field is possible, *as I need it*. Maybe this is isn't exactly what I'm looking for, it's a very unusual use case, but the requirement is also very unusual.

Any insights you can give are greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've forgotten to add the most crucial piece of information.

Most `CoreModel` will be removed for Postgres (the historic ones), but there's a tiny part of `CoreModel`s that will remain and will be moved after a while. In essence, only the "active" `CoreModel`s will stay in Postgres, but all will eventually be moved out, while new `CoreModel` will be created.

So that rules out the possibility of change the ForeignKey field for an integer.

Comment: Do you still need the foreign key field? Can you not replace it with an integer field since?

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank you for the question. I have added more information under the UPDATE title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could retain but rename the foreign key and then add a property with the old name

```
class SatelliteModel(models.Model):
    old_core = models.ForeignKey(CoreModel, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    @property
    def core(self):
        try:
            return self.old_core
        except CoreModel.DoesNotExist:
            return aws_client.fetch_core()
```

This would change the column name in your schema, although you could override the column name to prevent this

```
old_core = models.ForeignKey(CoreModel, db_column='core_id', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

It may be possible to create a subclass of `ForeignKey` that would perform as you wished, if this answer is not sufficient I can share some thoughts

Comment: Would this require the creation of a migration?

Comment: @Sebastialonso almost any solution would require you to have a migration since `SatelliteModel.core` would no longer be a foreign key constraint?  For the instances where `CoreModel` has been migrated is the old id required to get the migrated data and what does the old column get set to?